# Can a naturally poisonous creature always use the feat Poison Spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, monsters, poison

If a creature is naturally poisonous, like an [aranea](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/aranea.htm) (*MM* 15-6) or a [couatl](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/couatl.htm) (*MM* 37-8), can the creature freely use the feat Poison Spell (*Und* 51) to poison all its spells that require a melee touch attack? According to the feat, "The dose of poison used as the component [necessary to employ the feat] is expended when you cast the [now-poisoned] spell, whether or not the spell or poison successfully affects the target." Is there something that makes the aranea or couatl care that it's just expended a dose of poison, given that it has, essentially, *limitless* doses of poison?

From a game balance perspective, unlimited poisoning of such a creature's spells *seems* reasonable--such a creature's spellcasting is usually below a comparable PC's spellcasting, so adding its poison to all its melee touch attack spells isn't nearly so horrifying as it might first appear (*and* it forces a spellcaster into melee, which is rarely pleasant)--but I was wondering if there were a limit that I might've missed or if the definition of a dose of poison somehow prevents a creature from using, or limits a creature's ability to use, the feat Poison Spell.

Comment: I can't give a proper answer to this but imho it would certainly make for some interesting encounters through some minor rules-lawyering. I'd only allow it for creatures that deliver poison through melee though; the two you cited deliver poison through a bite. So unless they're delivering touch spells with their mouth I'd rule they can't utilize the feat.

Comment: @Jason_c_o I understand you're proposing a house rule--that's cool, and you should totally answer the question; I didn't tag this RAW--, but bites are *already* melee; while *reality* differentiates between poisoned swords and poisonous fangs, the game concerns itself only with a poison's delivery method (e.g. contact, inhaled, ingested, injury). Further, I'm pretty sure nothing *prevents* a creature with a bite attack from holding a touch spell's charge in its mouth.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t **think** so; I’m reasonably sure you have to prepare doses of your venom ahead of time. *Drow of the Underdark* has this rule under Handle Animal on page 46:

> **Bestow Venom (DC 15):** By succeeding on a DC 15 Handle Animal check to handle a vermin that has a poison special attack, you can compel the vermin to give up some of its venom. The creature deposits its poison into a container you indicate, providing a single dose. A Handle Animal check to extract venom takes 1 minute. You can then attempt a DC 15 Craft (poisonmaking) check to refine this venom into a poison you can use.

So you don’t need to handle yourself, and can just dump a dose of venom into a suitable container, but it still needs to be refined using Craft (poisonmaking). Still, a minute’s preparation isn’t bad, and it costs you nothing to keep pumping these things out, so it’s not exactly *hard* to use Poison Spell as a venomous creature.

Comment: This makes sense if someone else wants to acquire venom from a vermin but doesn't really answer the question. If anything the craft(poisonmaking) to make it useful is because poisons and venoms work differently and it reflects the conversion **so that anyone but the original creature may use it effectively**. (Venom is injected into the bloodstream. Poisons may be ingested, inhaled, or may poison on contact). While this *is* a rule governing poison, I don't think it applies to the circumstance OP is inquiring about.

Comment: @Jason_c_o It’s the *only* rule, so far as I know, that so much as touches on using creature-poison as a weapon-poison. In absence of this rule, the two are separate and creature-poison cannot be used as weapon-poison at all.

Comment: Hmm.. If only it had a limit on how many times you could do it before the creature ran out of poison...